# How to get all <asp:Label> controls within an HTML Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm updating some old code that loops over a collection and sets some UI display properties based on the values in the object.

Unfortunately, it's hardcoded like so:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < length; i++) // length is going to be 30+
{
    // do some stuff

    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            lbl1.Text = myVariable;
            break;
        case 2:
            lbl2.Text = myVariable;
            break;
        ....
        case 15:
            lbl15.Text = myVariable;
            break;
    }
}
```

(I say unfortunately because it actually has 5 more lines per case that I left out, which do the exact same thing regardless of the case)

Now, I could put all 15 `label` controls in an array and in my `for` loop just do `if (i <= 15) lblArr[i].Text = myVariable;` but I'd prefer not to have to hardcode this array. If we add more labels then we'll need to remember to update this function.

So, I'm trying to find a way to find all the controls within a particular HTML element, but I cannot find a working example in a .NET language.

In winforms I could simply just iterate over `someControl.Controls` and find the appropriate ones, but since these are labels in an HTML table and not a repeater or anything like that I don't know how to find them. Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, if *length is going to be 30+*, why does the switch end at 15?

Comment: Are you really using a plain HTML table or is it an WebControl table that has runat server?

Comment: @Amit the collection I'm iterating over does a lot more than just setting some values on the page, however the first fifteen elements contain values for "extra" user-defined fields

Comment: @thewisegod Yes, it is an actual HTML table with asp labels dropped in the table data elements

Comment: You could always make your HTML table runat=server :)

Comment: @moarboilerplate What would that allow me to do?

Comment: @sab669 the reason you can't find anything about modifying plain HTML tables from the codebehind is because it's simply impossible unless the server is generating a control. You can use the runat="server" attribute to make the server generate a control for the table (that functions exactly like an html table) and will have a controls collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  the [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < length; i++) 
{
     Label ans = FindControl(string.Format("lbl{0}",i)) as Label ;
          if (ans!=null) and.Text = myVariable

}
```

Comment: I just left work but I think this should do what I want; I think they are all in fact "customlabel1,2,3" etc so that'd be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

How about jquery?   It's definteily much faster than .NET.  give it a shot... :)

```
$(function () {

    var myTableId = "yourTableId";
    var yourReplacementText = "yourReplacementText";
    var allSpansUnderYourTable = $('#' + myTableId).find('span');
    $.each(allSpan, function (index, item) {
        item.innerHTML = yourReplacementText;
    });
});
```

Comment: Then I'd need a way to pass values from the DB fetched on page load to this script

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the code, it may be cleaner to just retrieve a db row on page load, set it to a property on the codebehind (or put its data in an object that is a property on the page), and then bind to it using code blocks. You can get rid of all of the `<asp:Label>` elements that way too.

e.g.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><span><%: myObject.Property1 %></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

That way you can make all of your binding declarative and remove the need for procedural codebehind logic to loop through and set things.